# Issues in inserting currentDate into WebSQL from javascript in WebSQL

Tags: javascript, sqlite, datetime, web-sql, iso8601

I'm trying to use the current date and time to do INSERT and SELECT statements, but the data is not getting inserted in WebSQL. Below is my code:

```
CREATION..
myDb.transaction(function(tr) {
        tr.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stInfo (keyNum INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, timestamp varchar(255) );');         
});

INSERTION
function insert() {
 var timeStamp = getCurrentDate();  returns in format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
myDb.transaction(function(tr) {
          tr.executeSql("INSERT INTO stInfo('keyNum','timestamp') values(215424," + timeStamp + ");");              
 });
}
```

Comment: Try removing the comments around keyNum and timestamp in your insert statement.  That's the first thing that doesn't look right.

Answer (score 2):

Old post, but I will answer it anyway. Easiest would be:

```
tr.executeSql('INSERT INTO stInfo (keyNum, timestamp) VALUES (?,?)',["215424", timestamp]);
```

Also, watch your double and single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes to surround the timestamp:

```
tr.executeSql("INSERT INTO stInfo('keyNum','timestamp') values(215424,'" + timeStamp + "')");
```